# SVG: Draw marker on an image

Tags: svg, d3.js

I want to show some marker text on an SVG image.

The **marker-start** and **marker-end** attributes work perfectly with shapes like *circle* and *rectangle*. But nothing is displayed on an image. I just see the plain image with no markers.

Is it even possible to display a marker for an image? Any help would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure *how* you want a marker to be displayed on an image -- where would you put the marker points?  But no, it's not possible.  Read the SVG specs here:
http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/painting.html#Markers

If you just want "corners" on the image, you can draw a rectangle (with no stroke or fill) around the image and put markers on that.

Comment: I believe you are referring to the first sentence of the spec which says **"A marker is a symbol which is attached to one or more vertices of ‘path’, ‘line’, ‘polyline’ and ‘polygon’ elements"**. This leaves out images. Am I correct?

Comment: It does and it leaves out circle and rectangles too so I don't know what UA you're using that displays markers on those.

Comment: Noticing this comment after two years! I used D3 at the time and tested on several browsers. I believe the 'polyline' and 'polygon' part covers the circles and rectangles.